# how do i get data from an api consisting of api objects into a recycler view

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, kotlin-coroutines

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
val baseUrl = "https://api.open-meteo.com/"
lateinit var mainBinding : ActivityMainBinding
var postsList = ArrayList<DATACLASS>()


var curday = ArrayList<String>()


lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView

lateinit var adapter: DaysAdapter



override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    mainBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = mainBinding.root

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.DayCardsList)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)

    adapter = DaysAdapter(curday,this@MainActivity)
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter


    setContentView(view)
    showPosts()
}


fun showPosts(){
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build()

    val forecastAPI: ForecastAPI = retrofit.create(ForecastAPI::class.java)

    val call : Call<List<DATACLASS>> = forecastAPI.getWeatherData(51.00, 52.00, "Africa/Cairo")
    call.enqueue(object : Callback<List<DATACLASS>>
    {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<DATACLASS>>, response: Response<List<DATACLASS>>) {
            if (!response.isSuccessful)
            {                   
                mainBinding.hoursCurrentCondition.text = "error"
            }
            else
            {

                postsList = response.body() as ArrayList<DATACLASS>
                curday.add(mainBinding.hoursCurrentCondition.text = postsList[0].daily.time[0])

            }
            
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<DATACLASS>>, t: Throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, t.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

    }
    )
}
```

}

class DaysAdapter(

```
var tm : ArrayList<String>,

var context: Context ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<DaysAdapter.DaysViewHolder>() {


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DaysViewHolder {
    return DaysViewHolder(
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
            R.layout.day_cards,
            parent,
            false
        )
    )
}



override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return tm.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DaysViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val item = tm.get(position)

    holder.curday.text = tm.get(position)
}

class DaysViewHolder(itemView : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
{

    var curday: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dayDate)
}
```

}

I tried using Gson and to implement it and there there are much more complex ways to get this weather app to work but i tried almost everything and nothing of that has work i always face a blockage in the way, as i'm not familiar with api objects and api in general